# Spring SFTP Integration is not polling the file

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, sftp

I have to integrate Spring SFTP in my application . The idea is to listen to a SFTP path and if any file is dropped in SFTP , read the file and update the DB tables . But i think Spring SFTP inbound is to transfer the files between systems . I could not find a good example on how to achieve that .
below is the configuration i am trying , but nothing is happening even after i place this xml configuration . I need everything in XML configuration.
Can someone suggest me a example on how to achieve that or how i can modify my configuration to achieve the same.

```
<bean id="sftpSessionFactory" 
class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="hostname"/>
    <property name="port" value="22"/>
    <property name="user" value="vkp"/>
    <property name="password" value="1234"/>
</bean>
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpAdapterAutoCreate"
                                  session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
                                  channel="requestChannel"
                                  filename-pattern="*.txt"
                                  remote-directory="/tmp/charge/"
                                  local-directory="file:target/charge"
                                  auto-create-local-directory="true"
                                  local-filename-generator-expression="#this.toUpperCase() + '.a'"
                                  delete-remote-files="false">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this sample in the official repo: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/sftp

You really should be sure that you place there in the remote `/tmp/charge/` the file with a `.txt` extension.

You probably also need to turn on `DEBUG` logging level for the `org.springframework.integration` to be really sure what is going on in your application.

Comment: Thanks , It worked , i can see the files are polling and placing it in my target/charge folder as per configuration. But may i ask is there any way i can trigger my service layer to process the file and store the data in DB with or without downloading the file in target folder ?

Comment: See streaming channel adapter to avoid local file copy: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-streaming. To active a service level with the file or its content you need to use a service activator as a subscriber to the output channel of your channel adapter. You can find a service activator definition in the mention doc.