# How to get the file from service-activator Message object in listener class

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, sftp

I need to pass the file to service layer which  i am receiving in SFTP path.
below is configuration and i am seeing the message receiving in my service-activator like

```
GenericMessage [payload=com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$2@322906a2, 
headers={closableResource=org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession@379662a7, 
id=704c58e7-1d93-3bef-0330-233c0f9af55c, file_remoteDirectory=/tmp/charge/, 
file_remoteFile=Charge.txt, timestamp=1594158522576}]

<bean id="sftpSessionFactory" 
class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="hostname"/>
    <property name="port" value="22"/>
    <property name="user" value="vkp"/>
    <property name="password" value="1234"/>
    <property name="allowUnknownKeys" value="true"/>
</bean>
<int-sftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter id="sftpAdapterAutoCreate"
                                  session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
                                  filename-pattern="*.txt"
                                  channel="receiveChannel"
                                  remote-directory="/tmp/charge/">
</int-sftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter>

<int:poller fixed-rate="25000" max-messages-per-poll="1" id="shippingChargePoller" default="true"/>

<int:channel id="receiveChannel">
    <int:queue/>
</int:channel>

<int:stream-transformer id="withCharset" charset="UTF-8"    input- 
channel="receiveChannel" />

<int:service-activator id="FeedListener" input-channel="receiveChannel"  method="onMessage">
    <bean class="com.listener.ChargeFeedListener"/>
</int:service-activator>


   public void onMessage(Message<?> message){
    System.out.println(message.toString());
    System.out.println( " Received File is  "+message.getPayload());
}
```

But i am not receiving the file in my java class . What i need to do to get the file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, read documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-streaming. The `<int-sftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter>` is not about files. It does open an `InputStream` for a remote entry (probably file on SFTP) and let you to do with this stream whatever you want. For example (also according that docs), there is a `StreamTransformer` which let's you to read that stream into a `byte[]` or string if you provide a `charset`. If you really want to deal with files, then you need to consider to switch to the `<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>`. That one pull the remote entry and store its content into a local file. Then that `java.io.File` is sent to the channel for your consideration.

I think we had a chat with you on the matter in other your question: [Spring SFTP Integration is not polling the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62781759/spring-sftp-integration-is-not-polling-the-file..).

Please, let us know what is wrong with our docs that confuses you so you have to raise questions like this over here.

Comment: i added the transformer but i could not see the transformed String or byte[] in the message . I Updated my current configuration .Sorry ,  What i am missing .

Comment: What you have right now is like two subscribers to the same `receiveChannel`. Your `<int:stream-transformer>` may not get any messages at all. More over you don't have an `output-channel` on this transformer to send a result into. I'm not sure what is your logic, but probably you need to start from the theory and understand what is endpoint and channel: https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/. You probably would like to send a result of the transformer to that `FeedListener` service. So, make an `output-channel` of the transformer as an `input-channel` of the service-activator.